# How to get the font a website is using if request blocked?

Tags: web, fonts, download, frontend, http-status-code-403

I inspected a website by Chrome Dev Tools and found the font downloaded in Network tab. It appeared as a woff2 file and I want to use exactly this font in my personal website. However when I try to double click on it, or to open it in new tab, there was an error: 403 ERROR - The request could not be satisfied. [screenshot on this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elBHU.png)

I thought that the owner of the website blocked my request. How can I download this font file to use in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Copy -> copy response

Paste in another tab

Rename the file to .woff2

Use this converter https://kombu.kanejaku.org/ if you need any other format